# Change appearance of elements based on sequence stored in array

Tags: javascript

I have two quarters of a circle in two span tags:

```
<div>
  <span id="topleft"></span>
  <span id="topright"></span>
</div>

<button id = 'clickme' style = 'margin-top: 100px;'>CLICK ME</button>
```

When I click the button I want the divs to 'light up' based on a sequence stored in an array using JavaScript:

```
let reset = (position) => { 
  document.getElementById(position).style.opacity = 1; 
};

let blink = (position) => {
  document.getElementById(position).style.opacity = 0.5;
};

let sequence = (positions) => {

  let currentBlink = positions.pop();
  blink(currentBlink);
  setTimeout(reset.bind(null, currentBlink), 1000);

  if (positions.length > 0) {
    sequence(positions);
  }

}

document.getElementById('clickme').onclick = () => {
  sequence(positions);
}

let positions = ['topleft', 'topright'];
```

The problem is that both divs 'light up' at the same time where I actually want a pause between the two.

How can I achieve this effect?

Thanks any help appreciated.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/4pt1yhzx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke the function after `timeout` in callback.

```js
let reset = (position) => {
  document.getElementById(position).style.opacity = 1;
};

let blink = (position) => {
  document.getElementById(position).style.opacity = 0.5;
};

let sequence = (positions) => {
  let currentBlink = positions.pop();
  blink(currentBlink);
  setTimeout(function() {

    reset(currentBlink);
    if (positions.length > 0) {
      sequence(positions);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

document.getElementById('clickme').onclick = () => {
  sequence(positions);
}

let positions = ['topleft', 'topright'];
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="topleft">aaa</span>
  <span id="topright">aaa</span>
</div>
<button id='clickme' style='margin-top: 100px;'>CLICK ME</button>
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/4pt1yhzx/)